# How to record 4th input channel audio

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I have an audiocard with 4 input channels: mono, stereo, 3 , 4. Is there any sdk way to record 4th channel data? 
Now I just can record only mono/stereo by AudioRecord.

Comment: Android does not support that.You could probably use some lower-level linux functions, or NDK, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android docs for AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord), the only channel input configuration's available specified are AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO or AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO.

However, it seems that much higher number of channel outputs are supported according to the [AudioFormat docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat) (or are at least planned to be implemented if not already).

I think that this would be a challenge on its own to implement it yourself, but could be worthwhile doing (I didn't manage to see any obvious solutions for this or any open source code yet). However, an example on the app store does exist, so it is possible via the USB interface according to the [USB Audio Recorder Pro App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.usbaudiorecorderpro).

[JUCE](https://forum.juce.com/t/support-usb-audio-devices-on-android/19616) (a mostly audio based C++ library that can compile directly to Android .apk s) seems to be working on this as well but I haven't seen a solution to this yet (maybe in the very near future).

I think you would have to go directly into [OpenSL](https://googlesamples.github.io/android-audio-high-performance/guides/opensl_es.html) (C++ with JNI) to get the raw audio being received and then pass this back into Java to do whatever you wanted to do with it. Probably worth investigating OpenSL recording through USB devices with something like [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ndk/159x200qa3/how-to-use-opensl-es-with-usb-digital-audio-devices-headphones) to get started.

I know this is a lot of links, but hopefully it will get you started if you did want to implement this functionality (comment a link if you ever did start it).

Otherwise I hope this helped anyways!

Comment: Have recorded 4th channel audio. 
I use tinyalsa through jni. https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa
In this way, data is recorded from /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c, but it's needed root access or a+rw rights on pcmC1D0c.

Answer (score 0):

Have recorded 4th channel audio. I use tinyalsa through jni. [github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa](http://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa) 
In this way, data is recorded from /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c, but it's needed root access or a+rw rights on pcmC1D0c.